# How to add editable text inputs in Froala?

Tags: jquery, froala

I am trying to create template in Froala editor. This template needs to display editable text inputs. I am able to add inputs in code view and then see them on content view (see image attached), but I am not able to make these inputs editable on content view.
How to make inputs editable?

[image: How to make editable text input in froala]

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer for this.?

Answer (score 0):

The version 2.7.6 is allowing that by default. Please make sure you are using the right version: https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/changelog.